# How to set the default color of console output in the Powershell profile

Tags: powershell

I've been playing around with the Set-PSReadLineOption colors. I've finally got a dark-themed console that I like in my Windows PowerShell profile (except the console window's background which seems only possible to set manually).

One final change I'd like to make is to set the color for the output of generic commands, such as gci

```
131|PS(5.1.18362) C:\Users\....\wsPowerShell\Modules [210505-11:01:24]> gci


    Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules   #Color this line


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name              #Color this line
----                -------------         ------ ----              #Color this line
d-----       10/21/2020   2:41 PM                PSScriptAnalyzer  #Color this line
```

Currently the default color for the output of generic commands is white, and I'd prefer a light gray or dark green instead. I only know how to change this via the preferences menu as Screen Text.

Is there a way to customize this in the Windows PowerShell profile? I'd also be okay with coloring parts of the output if coloring the entire output isn't possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a profile to your current user and it will be loaded every time you open a console.
To check your profile path use the automatic variable `$profile`:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> $profile
C:\Users\myuser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

If the file exists, than you can modify it, when not, you have to create it first.
Now you are able to configure what you want, for example:

```
$Host.ui.rawui.backgroundcolor = "white"
$Host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = "black"
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles

In this way you can modify the attributes of the texts, but not the console background itself. It can be done with parameters only in ISE, in normal console you do not have a parameter to use.

In ISE profile:

```
$Host.PrivateData.ConsolePaneBackgroundColor = "black"
```

There are some coloring parameter, that you can change in normal console too:

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> $host.PrivateData

ErrorForegroundColor    : Red
ErrorBackgroundColor    : Black
WarningForegroundColor  : Yellow
WarningBackgroundColor  : Black
DebugForegroundColor    : Yellow
DebugBackgroundColor    : Black
VerboseForegroundColor  : Yellow
VerboseBackgroundColor  : Black
ProgressForegroundColor : Yellow
ProgressBackgroundColor : DarkCyan
```

To what you propably want, add the folowing to your profile:

```
cmd /c color 0f
```

(It makes bright white text on black background - of course you can modify the parameters)
Reference: https://ss64.com/nt/color.html